# JOIN expression not supported MS Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to create a simple query in MS Access 2013. This this the SQL I've got so far:

```
SELECT CDRtblID, Call_Date, Call_Time, Duration, Salesprice
FROM tblTrilanCDR
INNER JOIN tblCustomer
ON CDRtblID = CDRtblID
```

I'm getting the error:

```
"JOIN expression not supported"
```

I'm new to SQL and programming in general. I know that it's possible (and much easier) to just create a standard query in Access 2013, but that would defeat the whole point in learning basic SQL commands!

I'll be very grateful to anyone who can contribute.

Comment: Fix your `ON` clause as it points to same field.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL expression contain ambiguous (or erroneous) join: `CDRtblID = CDRtblID`. Enter it with explicit Table names and it should work (provided that both Tables contain that field), like in the following example:

```
SELECT CDRtblID, Call_Date, Call_Time, Duration, Salesprice 
FROM tblTrilanCDR 
INNER JOIN tblCustomer ON tblTrilanCDR.CDRtblID = tblCustomer.CDRtblID
```

Hope this may help.